# Global variable for secure data

Tags: c#

I need a variable to which access will have different forms of my application.

In this variable I want to store a password. I want to know how best to define this variable? Through a delegate?

CSP? (But CSP for asymmetric keys, right?) Some isolated storage? or just method for example static class in Program.cs:

```
static class Data
{
    public static string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I ask this because I want to protect themselves against Trojan horses that can get access to my process, you know like ArtMoney :)

Comment: How about [`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure you already know this, but I'll restate it just to make sure: *You can't protect your app from Trojans running on the same machine.* You can just make it harder for them.

That said, the [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class ensures that the password is in (unencrypted) memory only as short as possible, thus making it harder for another process to extract that information.

Note that *reading* the value stored in the SecureString is not so easy, not even for your own application. An example on how to do that can be found in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/05/27/143254.aspx), which converts it to a BSTR:

```
IntPtr bstr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(password);

try
{
    // ...
    // use the bstr
    // ...
}
finally
{
    Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(bstr);
}
```

The string is *deliberately* not converted to a managed string, which would, again, linger around unencrypted in managed memory until it is garbage collected. The correct way would be to interact directly with the BSTR (which is zeroed out in the finally block), for example, using `Marshal.ReadByte`. And example can be found in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2005/08/15/422525.aspx).

Comment: I understand that there is no perfect way to protect themselves. Keep the password in a temporary file awful. Store in a Public variable is not ideal.

I want to know which way is better. Perfect does not is real, I'm aware of that. I want to know about the best option.

SecureString - this is the best option as I understand it?

Comment: @MaximDroy: Yes, as far as I know. You do need to have it in memory *one way or another*, to be able to work with it, and SecureString at least makes it hard to extract.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) class.
It is supposed to securely store passwords in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Windows ProtectedStorage for this.